# Search String Pattern in Large Text Files C#

Tags: c#, string

I have been trying to search string patterns in a large text file. I am reading line by line and checking each line which is causing a lot of time. I did try with `HashSet` and `ReadAllLines`.
`HashSet<string> strings = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Doc\Tst.txt"));`

Now when I am trying to search the string, it's not matching. As it is looking for a match of the entire row. I just want to check if the string appears in the row.

**I had tried by using this:**

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"D:\Doc\Tst.txt"))
                {

                    while ((CurrentLine = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        vals = chk_log(CurrentLine, date_Format, (range.Cells[i][counter]).Value2, vals);
                        if (vals == true)
                            break;
                    }
                }



bool chk_log(string LineText, string date_to_chk, string publisher, bool tvals)
        {
            if (LineText.Contains(date_to_chk))
                if (LineText.Contains(publisher))
                {
                    tvals = true;
                }
                else
                    tvals = false;
            else tvals = false;
            return tvals;

        }
```

But this is consuming too much time. Any help on this would be good.

Comment: do you need this only to check if somewhere in file there is presence of required pattern? you can you `Parallel` to improve speed to multicore CPUs

Comment: yes i have to look for 2 patterns in a line. But the file is big and I have to do this type of searching for other patterns too

Comment: What is the number of lines? What is `(range.Cells[i][counter]).Value2`?

Comment: (range.Cells[i][counter]).Value2  this is a string. No of lines is about 65000

Comment: First define how much "too much" is, or in other words what perf you want to achieve. Then use a profiler to find out where exactly the time is spent (e.g. whatever `(range.Cells[i][counter]).Value2` actually is doing, for example, you could do it only once (since the expression is not affected by the "current line"))

Answer (score 2):

Reading into a `HashSet` doesn't make sense to me (unless there are a lot of duplicated lines) since you aren't testing for membership of the set.

Taking a really naive approach you could just do this.

```
var isItThere = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\docs\st.txt").Any(x => 
    x.Contains(date_to_chk) && x.Contains(publisher));
```

65K lines at (say) 1K a line isn't a lot of memory to worry about, and I personally wouldn't bother with `Parallel` since it sounds like it would be superfast to do anyway.

You could replace `Any` where `First` to find the first result or `Where` to get an `IEnumerable<string>` containing all results.

Comment: You are missing a bracket somwhere in your code. The `Any` one is not closed.

Comment: @Nefrin should be `&& x.Contains(publisher));`

Comment: @Jeff , thanks for the solution . It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a compiled regular expression instead of `String.Contains` (compile once before looping over the lines). This typically gives better performance.

```
var regex = new Regex($"{date}|{publisher}", RegexOptions.Compiled);

foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"D:\Doc\Tst.txt"))
{
    if (regex.IsMatch(line)) break;
}
```

This also shows a convenient standard library function for reading a file line by line.

Or, depending on what you want to do...

```
var isItThere = File.ReadLines(@"D:\Doc\Tst.txt").Any(regex.IsMatch);
```